# SQL server and PHP restart

Tags: php, sql-server, apache-2.4

i have Apache/PHP running on a server running windows 7 with SQL server 2008 r2 running on windows Server 2008.

When SQL is restarted Apache/php will no longer connect to SQL once it is back up however restarting the Apache/PHP allows the connection to work once it's back up.

Any ideas how i can solve this without restarting Apache?

Comment: You must be using persistent connections. The only option which I am aware of would be to not use persistent connections. I hope someone else knows of a better solution though

Comment: Error messages?  What are you using to connect to SQL Server from PHP?

Comment: I am using  ODBC